# RSS not appearing in meta tag

Tags: 7, feeds

An RSS-feed on my site doesn't show up in the HTML `<head>` as it is supposed to, which makes it very difficult to find. Here's my situation:

- A view is displaying the latest blog posts.
- This view has two displays: a content pane and a feed. The feed is attached to the
  content pane.
- The content pane is shown on a page using panels and page manager.

The RSS-icon shows up at the bottom of the view, so the feed is definitely there. However, the feed doesn't show up in the the meta-tags, so the browser doesn't discover the feed like it's supposed to. Does anyone know where this goes wrong, and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue before. As you mentioned, feed auto-discovery works through the link in the  tag (see http://diveintohtml5.info/semantics.html#rel-alternate for more info).

I found that some themes and modules add it in automatically, while others don't. If yours is absent, you can auto-discover the default drupal RSS feed by adding the following to a preprocess function:

```
$element = array(
  '#tag' => 'link', 
  '#attributes' => array( 
    'href' => '/rss.xml', 
    'rel' => 'alternate',
  ),
);
drupal_add_html_head($element, 'mymodule');
```

Alternatively, you could just add it into the html.tpl.php file, as mentioned in this post: http://www.webbykat.com/2012/03/adding-feedburner-rss-link-your-theme-drupal-7-omega

Regarding Views, I have found that enabling auto discovery means adding a "Feed" display then turning on the setting at `Feed Settings > Attach To > Master`, as you did. You can also set it to include other displays to get the RSS icon to display in those views.