# How can I get my RSS feed to be Auto Discovered?

Tags: views, 8

Created an RSS feed in Drupal 8 using Views.  The feed is fine, but yet I don't have the discoverability icon show up in browsers.  Looking at the HTML source I don't see anything like this at all

I found this [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/58791/12881) for Drupal 7 but doing *"Feed Settings > Attach To > Master"* had no affect.

Answer (score 0):

Attach the Feed display to a valid Page display. The "Master" display may not be a valid page display.

An example of this can be seen in the default "Front Page" view. In this view, the feed display is attached to page_1, which is the page at the URL `/node`.

See the YAML export snippet from views.view.frontpage.yml below:

```
  feed_1:
    display_plugin: feed
    id: feed_1
    display_title: Feed
    position: 2
    display_options:
      sitename_title: true
      path: rss.xml
      displays:
        page_1: page_1
        default: ''
```

Comment: Ahh  I think I see the issue.  I just have a Feed, no Page at all ( which is why I just see Master )